# How to transform an "extends" from the vue class-api into the vue composition-api?

Tags: vue.js, inheritance, extends, vue-composition-api

I have two components, that I would like to transform into composition api

Base component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>prop type: {{ typeof message }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseComponent",
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Extended component:

```
<script>
import BaseComponent from "./BaseComponent";

export default {
  name: "ExtendedComponent",
  extends: BaseComponent,
  props: {
    message: {
      type: Number,
      required: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

When changing both components into composition API, I run into issues and the inheritance does not seem to work properly. It doesn't seem to pass the right prop either. Am I missing something here? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Inheritance is no longer a thing in Vue 3. Composition is meant to replace inheritance. In Vue 3, state that should be shared between components should be made into a [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html)